# CORS Origin Spring Boot Jhipster - pre-flight fails

Tags: spring-boot, cors, yaml, jhipster

I am using jhipster v2.27.2
I have enabled cors by uncommenting the lines in the application.yml

```
jhipster:
async:
    corePoolSize: 2
    maxPoolSize: 50
    queueCapacity: 10000

cors: #By default CORS are not enabled. Uncomment to enable.
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers:
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

In the "WebConfigurer"

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = props.getCors();
        if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth/**", config);
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

But still when I request for the access token, I see this error

> http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9090' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like in the default `SecurityConfiguration`, its not skipping security check for OPTIONS.

Try adding the following `antMatcher` to the `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` method in `SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
.antMatchers(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this issue will come if you forget to register cors on specified URLs.In WebConfigurer look for corsFilter and and add these line

```
 log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option in the `SecurityConfiguration.java`. Instead of using `antMatcher` within the `configure(HttpSecurity)` override, is to add it within the `configure(WebSecurity)` override...

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
```